# An efficient way to create a static list with n number of objects

Tags: angular, abstract

I have a angular component, typically I would store this information in a database, and retrieve it from there and build out this list. However, I am doing this as part of a learning process of Ionic framework, so I create it in the component itself.

I have the following static list that I create:

```
export class Foo{
 constructor(){

 this.list= [
      {
        Id: 0, Line: "zero"
      },
      {
        Id: 1, Line: "one"
      },
      {
        Id: 2, Line: "two"
      },
      {
        Id: 3, Line: "three"
      },
      {
        Id: 4, Line: "four"
      },
      {
        Id: 5, Line: "five"
      },
      {
        Id: 6, Line: "six"
      },
      {
        Id: 7, Line: "seven"
      },
      {
        Id: 8, Line: "eight"
      },
      {
        Id: 9, Line: "nine
      },
      {
        Id: 10, Line: "ten"
      },
      {
        Id: 11, Line: "eleven"
      },
      {
        Id: 12, Line: "twelve"
      },
      {
        Id: 13, Line: "thirteen"
      },
      {
        Id: 14, Line: "fourtheen"
      },
      {
        Id: 15, Line: "fiftheen"
      },
      {
        Id: 16, Line: "sixteen"
      },
      {
        Id: 17, Line: "seventeen"
      },
      {
        Id: 18, Line: "eighteen"
      },
      {
        Id: 19, Line: "nineteen"
      },
      {
        Id: 20, Line: "twenty"
      }
   ]
}
}
```

Now this list can have an n number of objects, so the lines will grow as the number grows - how can i abstract this out?

Comment: You mean converting the numbers to words as well?

Comment: no, I am looking for a way to take the creation of this list out of the component, and not have it so large in terms of lines of code?

Comment: Why dont you create a file with the data and just export it as a variable and import it in your component?

Comment: Do you want to display this list in a component? You can convert into array with `Object.keys()` and loop through with *ngFor https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor

Comment: Now, if what you want is only to handle your list. You can create an observable type Subject and use the `.next()` method to add items to your list

Comment: no that is not what I am after - i already consume this list in an *ngFor. What I am after is, taking the list out of the component and importing it in

Comment: @callback what type of file would this be? a js?

Comment: @Haris, a TS file. Export a variable that contains that data and import it in the component.

Comment: yeah i guess this will work well for what I need. thanks :)